# Loop through Oracle Cursor and Save excel file as string variable

Tags: arrays, string, oracle, python-2.7, for-loop

```
import CX_Oracle
Import xlwt
SQL0 = "SELECT COUNTRY FROM COUNTRYLIST"
cursor0 = con.cursor()
cursor0.execute(SQL0)

for country in cursor0:
    SQL = "SELECT * from TABLE WHERE COUNTRY = %s" % country
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute(SQL)
    book = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet1 = book.add_sheet('Summary')
    for i, row in enumerate(cursor):
        for j, col in enumerate(row):
            sheet1.write(i+1,j,col)  #Starts pasting the data at row 2
    book.save('Output_' + str(country) + '.xls')
```

This loops through each Country correctly with the correct data in each file, however, each of the excel files are being saved as such OUTPUT_('PERU',).xls

Answer (score 0):

Been looking everywhere on how to remove characters and couldn't figure it out.  It figures it was something so minor causing an error every time i tried to run it. I had to put str(country) in the re.sub for it to work.

```
countrys = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]+",'',str(country))
book.save('Output_' + countrys + '.xls')
```

Comment: Why not just `book.save('Output_' + country[0] + '.xls')` or `book.save('Output_{}.xls'.format(*country)`?